# How escape `()` in command linux for file python execute with `sys.args`?

Tags: shell

How to escape `()` in the linux command for python files run with `sys.argv`?

python

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    flow.loginAPI(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4],
    sys.argv[5],sys.argv[6],sys.argv[7],sys.argv[8],sys.argv[9],sys.argv[10],sys.argv[11]) # Send external command python
```

Command linux

```sh
$ python3 /etc/neural/scripts/ http://192.168.1.135/zabbix Admin zabbix Servers Production Memória em uso (Porcentagem) 0 127.0.0.1 networkneural postgres postgres MEMORYEXPORTZB
```

Output

```
-bash: error of syntax token unexpected `('
```

Comment: should you be surrounding the parameters with `""` ?

Comment: Returned: /usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/etc/neural/scripts/'

Comment: You have not specified a script name in your `python3 ... ` command

Comment: sorry, is correct your answer!

Comment: Escape is " ", I tried ' ', thanks a lot

Comment: Aside: `flow.loginAPI(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],...)` this is _very_ unreadable. Readability matters. Consider just `flow.loginAPI(*sys.argv[1:])` if you're consuming all arguments.

Comment: You don't escape something for "linux", you escape for a programming language (which may be a shell or Python, just for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply quote it: `"(Porcentagem)"`

Best practice is to quote anything with special characters, so also quote `"http://192.168.1.135/zabbix"` even if it doesn't make a difference.

BTW you can simplify your Python dramatically using [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-16) and [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
flow.loginAPI(*sys.argv[1:12])
```

Comment: @Luis Welcome! Actually it's not specific to `sys.argv`, it will work with any sequence type. I added some links for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`(` and  `)` are syntax for running a command in a subshell in bash

you can use:

```
\(Porcentagem\)
```

or

```
'(Porcentagem)'
```